# What should I do if the cache of the webpage causes the background images I set for different webpages to be cleared before they can be replaced?

Tags: css, web, caching, cookies

Is not a static web page. On most web pages, the html code is

```html
<body></body>
```

in one web page, the html code is

```html
<body id = "back1"></body>
```

the css code is

```
body {
    margin-left: 5em;
    background: url(img/background.png) repeat fixed;
}

#back1 {
    margin-left: 5em;
    background: url(img/back8.jpg) repeat fixed;
}
```

Because the browser cache will cause the background image to still be the image set in the previous page when the page is refreshed. For example, backback.png will become back8.jpg only after the cache is cleared

[Before clear cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kQ2d.png)[After clear cache, what I really want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAkSr.png)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Where exactly is the caching-related problem here?

Comment: Because the page cache will cause the background image to still be the image set in the previous page when the page is refreshed. For example, backback.png will become back8.jpg only after the cache is cleared

Comment: What “page cache”? Are you actually talking about the normal browser cache (in that case, I still can’t see what you are saying make much sense here), or about some caching mechanism of some sort of CMS/framework?

Comment: Well, I have updated the question and uploads the photos.